# Поправить работу функции по событию change jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть input, в который нужно ввести число.

```
     <div class="col-xs-6">
         <div id="allDebt" class="form-group">
               <label class="control-label" for="sumOfDebet">Сумма всей задолженности</label>
               <input name="sumOfDebet" class="form-control" id="sumOfDebet" type="text" required placeholder="Сумма всей задолженности">
                   <div class="error-box"></div>
         </div>
     </div>
```

И есть функция, в которой имеется условие: если значение input < 300000, то нужно выводить сообщение "Процедура банкротства не может быть введена в отношении данного лица"

```js
if (data.sumOfDebet <= 300000) {
            $('#allDebt').html('<div id="has-error" class="form-group has-error">' + '<label class="control-label" for="inputError1">' +
                'Процедура банкротства не может быть введена в отношении данного лица</label>' +
                ' <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputError1">' + '</div>');
            return;
        }
```

Проблема в том, что если после этого сообщения попытаться ввести другое число в этот input, то функция заново не начинает работать. (Вызывается она по событию change).

Как это можно поправить?

Comment: Приложите, пожалуйста, фрагмент js-кода, в котором реализован биндинг к текстовым полям и  обработка события `change`.

Comment: Приложите [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Потому что ты меняешь целый блок вместо того что бы обнулить значение `input` и просто менять текст `label`. и у тебя меняется `id` инпута.

Если тебе важно менять `id` то можно сделать захват события того `input`-а примерно так:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.sumOfDebet').on('change',function(){
    if ($(this).val() <= 300000) {
            $('#allDebt>label').text('Процедура банкротства не может быть введена в отношении данного лица');
            $(this).attr('id','inputError1')
                console.log('Сработало');
            return;
        }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-6">
         <div id="allDebt" class="form-group">
               <label class="control-label" for="sumOfDebet">Сумма всей задолженности</label>
               <input name="sumOfDebet" class="form-control sumOfDebet" id="sumOfDebet" type="text" required placeholder="Сумма всей задолженности">
                   <div class="error-box"></div>
         </div>
     </div>
```

Это пример реализации, так что бы событие работало всегда, но не полный пример того кода что вам нужно, поскольку в вопросе не отражалось весь ваш функционал, но кусок кода вы можете перенести и добавить в ваш код.